# Missing text in Google Translate

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-translate

I am running into a coding error while using the Google Translate HTML widget on my website. I've attached it to the header, but the words "Select Language" and even the "Powered by" is invisible? How would I ensure that this can be seen? Example URL: http://www.ovtbeta.com/EscuelaValdez/index.html

Thanks guys!

I've tried multiple different codes of the google translate widget, and the problem still persists.

I'm using:

```
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>
<script> 
    function googleTranslateElementInit() { 
        new google.translate.TranslateElement({
            pageLanguage: 'fr', 
            layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.HORIZONTAL 
        }
        , 'google_translate_element'); 
    } 
</script>
<script src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you included the relevant code in your question instead of posting only a link. With regards to your question, it looks like "Powered by" is visible. However, the color (controlled by class `.goog-te-gadget`) is set to `#666` which makes it very hard to see. Regarding `Select Language` it looks like `new google.translate.TranslateElement` doesn't add that in for you. Instead, you can manually add `Select Language` before `<div id="google_translate_element"></div>`

Comment: Thanks for the response. I found an earlier code that showed the select language over the drop down. As for the #666 - I do not see that under my CSS located in .goog-te-gadget. It simply says...

.goog-te-gadget {
  color: transparent;
}

.google_translate_element {
  width: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.google_translate_element a {
  display: none;
  width: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

Comment: It seems to be defined in `https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_static/css/translateelement.css` (external to your code). Try overriding in your code as follows: `.goog-te-gadget { color:white !important; }`. You can replace white with a color of your choice, though transparent will not work as it's, well, transparent.

Comment: Do you remember what you changed that caused "Select Language" to disappear?

Comment: I do not, I've tried replacing code and removing all goog-te-gadget and google.translate from CSS and the text still seems to be invisible. IT did work before, I will admit that.

Comment: Obviously, "Powered by" was invisible at the same time the Select Language became invisible. The Select Language is more important. As far as adding the text, I did, and it pushed the widget below it.

Comment: I'm using: <div id="google_translate_element"></div><script>
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({
    pageLanguage: 'fr',
    layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.HORIZONTAL
  }, 'google_translate_element');
}
</script><script src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>

Comment: Looks like "Select Language" is back, albeit invisible. Try adding this CSS rule: `.goog-te-combo { color: black; !important }`

Comment: Also just in case, after making the changes and to make sure you're seeing the latest version, clear your browser cache or use ctrl+F5 to do a cacheless refresh.

Comment: Thank you for helping! I'm uploading to see now. Curious, you know how I can remove the yellow box with Google Translate in it? Just to remove some attention to the fact that I can't remove it all together, lol.

Comment: Btw: It worked! Thank you so much! You're awesome!

Comment: Glad to hear it worked. To get rid of the orange background you could try `.goog-te-gadget > span { background-color:unset; }` You've got another rule on spans that is making it orange so you'll need to override it. If you want to remove the Google Translate box entirely you can do `display:none` instead of changing the background-color. That said, I'm check the terms and conditions for Google Translate first as you might be required to show the "Powered by Google Translate" part.

Comment: So would that be, ".goog-te-gadget { 
    color:white !important; 
    background-color: display:none;
    background-color: unset; 
}
"

Comment: No, `.goog-te-gadget > span` as we want to target the span directly beneath the goog-te-gadget

Comment: So my entire .goog-te-gadget now looks like this:

.goog-te-gadget { 
    color:white !important; 
}
.goog-te-gadget > span { background-color:unset; 

}

and the yellow seems to be there.

Comment: Looks like your CSS in `.header-top-info span` is taking priority. Try adding !important as follows:   .goog-te-gadget > span { background-color:unset !important; }` .  Also btw, if you are using a modern desktop browser (Chrome, Firefox, IE Edge, etc.)  you can press F12 to open up the web console, which you can use to see what CSS rules are being applied/overridden. You can also change HTML and CSS on the fly to test how things would look before you make the changes in the actual source.

Comment: Perfect. You're a genius. Thank you, seriously, for your help this evening. IT is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

please remove !important in your style.css (line 224).

```
.goog-te-gadget 
{
    color: transparent !important;
}
```

Comment: I removed it, as well as the rest of the tags below. The problem still seems to persist.